# How to update large dataset - several hundreds million documents - in mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using C# mongodb driver. Mongod version is 3. Update multiple is set to true { multi: true }. Trying to update all collections in a database, one by one. Is there any other thing that I can do to speed up?

Does update operation occur in RAM or does it go to hard disk?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collection.BulkWriteAsync` with `new BulkWriteOptions {IsOrdered = false}`. Unordered operation list allow server to execute operations in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is multithreaded but only by operation as presented by a client.   Once a thread picks up an operation, that single thread will complete the task.   If you can break up the filter component of the update into precise (and possibly non-overlapping) regions, and you can grok multithreaded programming, with 3.0 and the WiredTiger storage engine, you will significantly improve the overall throughput.

Updates hit the page in RAM and make it dirty, and the op is journaled (fast) for replay-recovery.  Dirty RAM pages are flushed much less frequently, like every 60 seconds.